# Where this picture was taken ~100 years ago?

Tags: russia, where-on-earth, identify-this, history

[image: Old photo]

It probably was taken in Russia/Estonia/Latvia/Lithuania during Russian Civil War by one of my ancestors.
I'm sure this place exists today - I saw it on the poster few years ago.
But place was not specified on the poster otherwise I wouldn't ask this.

There is some handwriting on the bottom of the picture but I can't read it.

Comment: Do you have a time machine?  Without one I'm not sure what relevance this question has to Travel?

Comment: This place still exists. You don't have to have time machine).

Comment: Have you try to read text in bottom of this image?

Comment: The reason to find it is just curiosity.
Tried to read - no luck.

Comment: Definitely not Latvia.

Comment: The handwriting says Каменец-Подольский, the name of the place as MikkaRin answered. It is hardly readable, but this name fits perfectly to parts that are readable.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[This](http://alex-brab.livejournal.com/149623.html) one looks like the one on your image.

The name of this building is Kamenez (Wikipedia: [Kamianets-Podilskyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamianets-Podilskyi)).

*Location*:

[image: location]

*Photo of our days*:
[image]